# If $f(x)=O(g(x))$ & $g(x)=O(f(x))$ then can we write $f(x)\sim g(x)$ or any other one-line relation?

Tags: functions, asymptotics

$f(x)=O(g(x))$ & $g(x)=O(f(x))$ then can we write $f(x)\sim g(x)$ or $$\lim_{x \to \infty}[f(x)/g(x)]=1$$ where f(x)=pi(x)(prime counting function) and g(x)=li(x)(logarithmic integral:li_x=Li_x-li_2)

Comment: No, but you can write $f(x) = \Theta(g(x))$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, generally speaking. For instance, if $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 2x$ then one has $f(x) = O(g(x))$ and $g(x)=O(f(x))$ but $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = 2.$$
Actually, it is also possible that there is no limit at all! For an example, take somthing like $f(x) = 2+\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=1$.

However, there is another notation corresponding to this case: $f(x) \asymp g(x)$, meaning that $f$ and $g$ have the same order of magnitude. An alternative definition is that
$$
0 < \liminf \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq \limsup \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < \infty.
$$
Notice that, like $\sim$, the notation $\asymp$ defines an equivalence relation.

**Concerning you edit.** In this special case, it is true that $\pi(x) \sim \mathrm{Li}(x)$ but this is a hard result known as the Prime Number Theorem (see [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) for a discussion on this subject).

Comment: really gud 1, but please see an edit made., I think you can give me an appropriate answer.

Comment: @ShivanshuSrivastava: Does this answers your question?

Comment: Thanks, but in my research paper, I had proved pi(x)=O(li(x)) & li(x)=O(pi(x)) then can I write pi(x)~li(x).?? (please disregard the fact that this is already a theorem !)

Comment: As I explained in my answer, it is not enough to prove $\pi(x) \sim \mathrm{Li(x)}$. You need some additional argument.

Comment: like what kind of additional arguments ?

Comment: @ShivanshuSrivastava: The kind of argument that filled the gap between the works of Chebyshev (1850) and the first proofs of the PNT by Hadamard and La Vallée Poussin (1896).

Answer (score 1):

It won't necessarily be true that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/g(x) = 1$, but it will be bounded.

For example, if $f(x) = 3x^2$ and $g(x) = x^2 + 1$, then the limit is $3$. And I think you could even come up with examples where the limit doesn't exist.

In general, $f(x) = O(g(x))$ means

$$
f(x) \leq C_1 g(x)
$$

(for $x \geq x_1$ for some $x_1$) and $g(x) = O(f(x))$ means

$$
g(x) \leq C_2 f(x)
$$

(similarly, for $x \geq x_2$)

so combining these, we have

$$
C_3 g(x) \leq f(x) \leq C_1 g(x)
$$

for $x \geq x_0 := \min(x_1,x_2)$ (and here $C_3 = \dfrac{1}{C_2}$) so we have

$$
C_3 \leq \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq C_1
$$

and from this, we can conclude the limit is *bounded*.

Comment: yeah, wiki says that but please see an edit made above (that  f(x)=pi(x)(prime counting function) and g(x)=li(x)(logarithmic integral:li_x=Li_x-li_2))